# Xamarin iOS. How to automatically go to end of the view

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to programmatically goto the bottom of the view for a xamarin iOS application?

I am not pasting any code as I am not able to find any. I am not even sure if its possible. Can anyone please advise?

I'm using MVVMCross if it helps..

Comment: Is this within a ScrollView?

Comment: It is a table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved.. I need to use this piece of code.

```
tableView.SetContentOffset(new CGPoint(0, tableView.ContentSize.Height - tableView.Frame.Size.Height), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach to take, is to scroll the table view to a given row, which would, in theory, be equal to the last row in the table.

For example, given the following table (theTable) we would scroll to the row which is equal to the final row in the table.

```
theTable.ScrollToRow(NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(theTable.NumberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1, 0), UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, true);
```

So what this code does, is computes the NSIndexPath for the final row (NumberOfRowsInSection -1 ) and then scrolls to that row.

In a basic table this is pretty straightforward, though additional variables (such as multiple table sections per TableView) complicate matters, and will require you to ensure the right section is selected.

So, to do this at the launch of the app:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    theTable.Source = new TableSource(tableyStuff);

    theTable.ScrollToRow(NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(theTable.NumberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1, 0), UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, true);
}
```

Please let me know if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Its crashing when i run that piece of code..
I am getting..

`Native stacktrace:

2016-07-26 09:30:40.898 iOS[79679:2437622] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================`

Comment: Are you able to provide code from the app where it crashes? I would like to test on my system. The code is functioning on my system.